# KVM guest to manage physical ethernet cards

Tags: firewall, ethernet, kvm-switch, centos-7

I've seen a system where was a physical machine (let's call it Hypervizor) that had 3-4 guests installed on. One of them was called Firewall and you could get to the Hypervizor only if you first SSH into the Firewall and then SSH over to the Hypervizor. Direct connection to the Hypervizor is unavailable, he is completely unreachable for the outside world.

How can I do the same on CentOS 7 with KVM? What is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 0):

The hypervizor machine is only listening for SSH connections on the internal virtual network. This can be done using `iptables` or `sshd` interface binding.

The firewall machine is only reachable over the network, which can be done in several ways. If you use open vswitch you can create a different internal network that is reachable from the outside network. If you give the firewall machine two interfaces (hypervizor only network and outside network) you can make this work.

Comment: What if I want to create only one Internal-LAN where I can connect to server1, sevrer2 and the hypervisor itself from the firewall? BTW the hypervisor was unreachable from anywhere, only from the firewall. So when you wanted to SSH into that machine, you had to go first to the firewall, then you could go to the hypervisor. If I create a virtual NIC for the hypervisor, disable the real ETH then could that work?